# I cant understand this Applet and Thread code in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

So I am currently learning Java applets and have this code that involves an Applet and a Thread in order to make an applet scroll a message string using repaint() method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/*
<applet code="Banner" width=300 height=50>
</applet>
*/

public class Banner extends Applet implements Runnable
{
    String msg = " Java Rules the Web ";
    Thread t;
    boolean stopFlag;

    public void init()
    {
        t = null;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        t = new Thread(this);
        stopFlag = false;
        t.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            try
            {
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(250);
                if(stopFlag)
                    break;
            }
            catch(InterruptedException exc)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        stopFlag = true;
        t = null;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
char ch;
    ch = msg.charAt(0);
        msg = msg.substring(1, msg.length());
        msg += ch;
        g.drawString(msg,50,30);
    }
}
```

So the problem is that I dont understand why init initialize Thread in null, when does start method is called and when init method is called, also when does the stop method is called in order to set stopFlag to false and how does this final part make the String to scroll:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
char ch;
    ch = msg.charAt(0);
        msg = msg.substring(1, msg.length());
        msg += ch;
        g.drawString(msg,50,30);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You realize there's no reason to learn applets?  They're all but dead.  That said, there's no reason here for `init()` to set `Thread t` to null.  `t` is already null from when the applet class is first loaded or when `stop()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applet container calls init when it creates the applet, start when it makes the applet visible, and stop when the applet goes away (like you leave the page hosting the applet).  Setting the t field to null in the init method doesn't do anything, since it will be null when the object is created anyway.  The message is scrolled by taking a character from the start of the string and putting it at the end of the string, then re-displaying the string in the applet window.  The thread does this every 250 ms until the applet is stopped.

Applets are a dead technology.

Comment: Addendum: applet containers have for a long time called both `init()` and `start()` in quick succession when an applet becomes visible, and `stop()` and `destroy()` in quick succession when it is no longer visible.  Moral: you can't actually rely on the timing of those four methods, they're up to the container.